# Difference between two times in minutes

Tags: java, time

I've seen some examples using Joda Time and other methods  to work out the difference between two dates in milliseconds, but how can these be applied to just get the difference between two times in minutes? For example, the difference between 2:45pm and 11:00am is 225 minutes.

Comment: Sorry I don't think my question was that clear I want to know how I can get the difference from two times in minutes instead of two dates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can work out the math by observing that one minute is sixty seconds, one second is one thousand milliseconds, so one minute is `60*1000` milliseconds.

If you divide milliseconds by 60,000, seconds will be truncated. You should divide the number by 1000 to truncate milliseconds, then take `n % 60` as the number of seconds and `n / 60` as the number of minutes:

```
Date d1 = ...
Date d2 = ...
long diffMs = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
long diffSec = diffMs / 1000;
long min = diffSec / 60;
long sec = diffSec % 60;
System.out.println("The difference is "+min+" minutes and "+sec+" seconds.");
```

Comment: I know this I just want to know how I can get the actual difference between the two times in the first place instead of 2 dates

Comment: Would d1 be entered as one string such as 0225? Would it also be in 24 hour time?

Comment: @user2704743 `d1` and `d2` are not strings, they are `java.util.Date` objects. There are different ways to enter them, depending on the locale. Look up "parsing dates in Java" to see the format in which you could enter these dates. Also look up Java Calendar for another option for making dates.

Answer (score 4):

With `JodaTime`, you can do the following to get exact minutes

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   //Read user input into the array
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); // current time
    DateTime time1 = new DateTime(time);
    DateTime time2 = new DateTime(time + 120_000); // add 2 minutes for example
    Minutes minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(time1, time2);
    System.out.println(minutes.getMinutes()); // prints 2
}
```

The [`Minutes.minutesBetween()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#minutesBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) accepts a [`ReadableInstant`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html) parameter which isn't necessarily a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

To convert milliseconds to minutes, divide by `60000`.