# How can i check the difference in minutes when comparing current date with the previous date

Tags: java

I have got a date in this format: `2015-07-29 16:29:32`

How can I check the difference in minutes between the current date and the given date?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String datetocomparestr = "2015-07-29 16:29:32";
        SimpleDateFormat datetocomparesdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
        Date d1 = null;
          d1 = datetocomparesdf.parse(datetocomparestr);
          System.out.println(d1);
          SimpleDateFormat dateFormatcurrentsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          Date date = new Date();
          System.out.println(dateFormatcurrentsdf.format(date));

    }
}
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686575/difference-between-two-times-in-minutes

Comment: This should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106532/get-date-representation-in-seconds

Comment: [Calculate date/time difference in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use the `Date.getTime()` method (returns "*milliseconds since 1.1.1970*"), get the difference of these values and divide that value by 1000 * 60 (1000 ms per second, 60 seconds per minute).

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? Just use the `long` representation of java to determine the time:

```
long timeToComp = parseSomeTime().getTime();
long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();

long dif = timeCurrent - timeToComp;
long mins = dif / (1000 * 60);//dif is the number of milliseconds between the current date and the parsed one
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [localdatetime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as below

```
LocalDateTime d1=new LocalDateTime(date1);
LocalDateTime d2=new LocalDateTime(now);

int minutesDiff=Minutes.minutesBetween(d1, d2).getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
double minutes = (date.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`Date#getTime()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) in Java returns the time in milliseconds.

Add the following to your code.

```
 long minutesDiff = (date.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;    //convert to minutes
 System.out.println("Difference in minutes : " + minutesDiff);
```

Check out this live [**demo**](http://ideone.com/UaJnBS).

Here is the complete code.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String datetocomparestr = "2015-07-29 16:29:32";
        SimpleDateFormat datetocomparesdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
        Date d1 = null;
        d1 = datetocomparesdf.parse(datetocomparestr);
        System.out.println(d1);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatcurrentsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormatcurrentsdf.format(date));

        long minutesDiff = (date.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
        System.out.println("Difference in minutes : " + minutesDiff);

    }
}
```