# Working out time between 7am to 3:30pm - JAVA

Tags: java, time, timedelta, calculation

I've created this program to calculate the time between startWork and finishWork
but I cant seem to figure out how to calculate time...
This is my Interface.
[image: Image of GUI]

Just wanting to know a way of approaching this calculation.

Thanks

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686575/difference-between-two-times-in-minutes

Comment: Please include your code in the question instead of a picture it.

Comment: I haven't got the code for the calculation as I'm not sure where to start...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8: Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime)

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. What did your search bring up?

Comment: Really rather a duplicate of [Calculating the time difference between two times in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876974/calculating-the-time-difference-between-two-times-in-java).

Comment: You should post a sample code for code review - avoid asking solution.

Comment: @JoeC No, not a duplicate of [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime) which is about much larger scale of time. And the Answer should be using `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime` to account for Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies.

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.time` as suggested by `Ole V.V.`:

```
String time1 = "07:00:00";
String time2 = "15:30:12";
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse(time1);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse(time2);
Duration diff = Duration.between(t1, t2);
System.out.println(diff.toString());
```

Prints:

> PT8H30M12S

Comment: So with that code from 07:00:00 to 15:00:00 it prints 8 which is correct
If I change it to 07:00:00 to 15:30:00 it prints 8 which is incorrect
How would I got about changing the output to print 8.5?

Comment: Please note that `java.util.Date` is legacy.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Not to mention its `LocalTime`, which matches the needs much better than the outmoded `Date`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you i have updated answer..

Comment: Using `LocalTime` fails to account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time(DST).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Duration` class from `java.time` to represent your working time. Let `Duration.between()` do the calculation for you, passing two `LocalTime` or two `ZonedDateTime` objects to it as appropriate. The latter will take transitions to and from summer time (DST) into the calculation if such a transition happens during the working hours.

If the time is entered as for example `1530` or `3:30pm`, define a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse it into `LocalTime`.

`Duration` objects can be summed using its `plus` method, so you can calculate the hourly and monthly working time and so on.

To format the working time into for example `8.5` (for 8 hours 30 minutes), use the `toMinutes` method, then convert to `double` before you divide by 60 (I would declare the constant 60 as `final double minutesPerHour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1);`).

### java.time

`java.time` is the modern Java date and time API. It came out nearly 4 years ago to replace the outdated and poorly designed date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1 from the last years of the previous millennium.

**Link:** [Oracle Tutorial trail Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)